# Flickering problem when updating image by using both img tag or background image in CSS

Tags: javascript, html, css, image, vuejs2

I have a problem solving a flickering when trying to display an updated version of an image (type of .webp).

The single image is a group of images merged into one (URL: `https://somePath/imageId.webp`).
In the background, the number of images grows over time.
I need to display updated version of image by using same URL, whenever the user requires that - it's expect to be frequently, on every click.

1. I used `background-image` CSS attribute to get and display an image. The problems with this approach were:

- To get updated version of an image, I need to add a query parameter to URL to trigger update, for example: `https://somePath/imageId.webp?timestamp=0.20389333335403492`
- After this change, flickering was too frequent (on every user 'updated image' request)
  `<div style="{'background-image':url(${imageUrl}),'background-repeat':'no-repeat'}"/>`

2. Also, I tried `img` tag instead of `background-image`, and it works fine - there's no need for query parameter in URL, but the flickering is still visible during re-rendering:
   `<img src="imageUrl" />`

[Here's a code example](https://jsfiddle.net/__akra/u98r4oq0/251/)

Comment: I do not see any flickering in your example. Can you elaborate more about the problem?

Comment: I solved problem by converting `imageUrl` into base64. The preview is always updated without flickering.

Comment: @Jose Here's updated example: https://jsfiddle.net/__akra/u98r4oq0/257/ I've added few more images for better visual tracking.

An image is a collection of images (~10 images) that changes over time. In current moment I can get 5 of them, but in few seconds there's for example 7 of them - that kind of update I need to display. 
Whenever image URL changes (new images collection) the one flicker happens in case of using `src` tag. With `background-image` this happens on every user requirement for new update.

Converting `imageUrl` into base64 solve this problem but burdens the system a lot.